# how to display default image in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am using Recycler View in android, my recycler view contains one ImageView and TextView,

when i get data from JSON response, recycler view shows only textView until Network image is not fully loaded , i want to show default image (For ex. Image from drawable folder) in ImageView until network image loads , once when network image load it replace default image , how can i achieve this??...

here is my adapter code :

```
@Override
public ViewHolderVideos onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.videos, parent,false);
    ViewHolderVideos viewHolder = new ViewHolderVideos(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderVideos holder, int position) {

    VideoData currentVideos = listVideos.get(position);
    holder.video_title.setText(currentVideos.getTitle());
    String urlThumbnail = currentVideos.getUrlThumbnail();
    loadImages(urlThumbnail, holder);
}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener){
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

private void loadImages(String urlThumbnail, final ViewHolderVideos holder) {
    if ((!urlThumbnail.equals(Constants.NA))){
        imageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate){
                holder.video_thumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                holder.video_thumbnail.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        holder.video_thumbnail.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use volley ,you can do this :

```
ImageListener listener = ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView,  
        R.drawable.default_image, R.drawable.failed_image); 
imageLoader.get(url, listener);
```